# Tag number at wrong place in an align environment

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, tags, gather

I'm having a problem in numbering some equations in this MWE code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Blabla blablabla bla:
\begin{align}
    A &= BBBBB \nonumber \\[1ex]
    &= CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC. \label{label1}
\intertext{Some blabla blabla blabla bla bla bla :}
    B &=
\begin{gathered}[t]
    DDDDD \\[1ex]
    \mathclap{= DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD.} \label{label2}
\end{gathered}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

I need the lines "A =" and "B =" to be aligned to their equal sign, without numbering, as currently done.  I need that intertext line between both parts.  Line "B =" should not be numbered, but the last line (a long centered math expression) should be numbered.  How can I do that?

As an alternative, both parts could have their number between their lines, i.e (1) between the first two lines, and number (2) between the last two lines.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ok, adding some split environment fixes the issue.

Comment: Or, try moving the second label after `\end{gathered}`.

Comment: What is wrong with `\MoveEqLeft`? `\begin{align}
    A &= BBBBB \notag \\[1ex]
    &= CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC. \label{label1}
\intertext{Some blabla blabla blabla bla bla bla :}
    B &=
    DDDDD \notag\\[1ex]
 \MoveEqLeft = DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD. \label{label2}
\end{align}`?